# Jenkins jobs disappear after installing & upgrading plugins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I installed several new plugins for Jenkins (Checkstyle, DRY, FindBugs, PMD, Warnings and Task Scanner) as well as upgrading all existing plugins that had upgrades available. After restarting Jenkins, nearly all of my jobs have disappeared from the dashboard. I tried disabling the new plugins and restarting again, but they are still not there.

Looking in the Jenkins log, I can see a NoSuchMethodError exception being thrown for each job that has disappeared:

```
Jul 09, 2013 1:09:22 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onTaskFailed
SEVERE: Failed Loading job algo
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProject.triggers()Lhudson/util/DescribableList;
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProject.createTransientActions(AbstractMavenProject.java:187)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.createTransientActions(MavenModuleSet.java:464)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.updateTransientActions(AbstractProject.java:717)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.updateTransientActions(MavenModuleSet.java:460)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.onLoad(AbstractProject.java:316)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.onLoad(MavenModuleSet.java:762)
    at hudson.model.Items.load(Items.java:221)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$17.run(Jenkins.java:2542)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:146)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:893)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

What could be the problem? I am using Jenkins version 1.516.

Comment: Do you still have the jobs folders under the JENKINS_HOME/jobs? How did you disable a plugin? Did you remove it completely?

Comment: The job folders are still there and I disabled the plugins via the "manage plugins" page. Anyway, upgrading from 1.516 to 1.522 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrading Jenkins to the latest version (1.522) fixed this problem.

Comment: I needed to upgrade all plugins to fix the same problem, which also appeared after an upgrade.

Comment: unforunately this problem still persists on the latest Hudson :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem was fixed after updating Maven Project Plugin to version 1.522 or newest.

Comment: Jobs also disappear in Jenkins ver. 1.549. Config.xml has 7 strings in a specific: views/listView/jobNames but the webpage only shows 4 while the directories are present in jobs.